# Trigger and read jenkin console logs

Tags: python, java, jenkins

I am planning to automate triggering jenkins job and read console logs to validate.
Currently I am able to trigger jenkins build using java.
Is there a way to read console logs using java?

Which other language will be useful to perform the same task?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the logs for any job by sending a simple GET request to the log url. For example, if you had a job called `test` and you wanted to get the logs of build `5`, use:

```
http://<host>:<port>/job/test/5/consoleText
```

You can call this url the same way you would call any regular endpoint with Java (or any other language), and you will get the logs in plain text.

**EDIT:** Once the job has been triggered, that build will be the last one that has run in that job. Therefore. you can get the build number by calling:

```
http://<host>:<port>/job/test/lastBuild/buildNumber
```

In the same way you would call any other endpoint. This works even if you trigger multiple builds on the same job. Make sure you get the build number from the above URL and save it in an array every time you trigger a new job.

Comment: As I mentioned, I am able to trigger jenkins job but how to get build no? Also will be triggering multiple jenkin builds one after the other. I need to get corresponding build no. Without build no , i cant execute above API call to get consoleText

Comment: @Venu I have edited the answer to show how you can get the build number of the last build.